# Exporting multiple lists (x1,y1...n) (x2,y2..n)of different lengths into same excel files separated by spaces of two columns between each (x,y) list?

Tags: list-manipulation, export, excel

I have multiple lists like this this with different lengths and different x, y values,

```
list1 = {{3., 1.49463}, {3.1, 1.49238}, {3.2, 1.49027}, {3.3, 1.48814}, {3.4, 
  1.48592}, {3.5, 1.48366}, {3.6, 1.48158}, {3.7, 1.47997}, {3.8, 
  1.47894}, {3.9, 1.47848}, {4., 1.47824}, {4.1, 1.47892}, {4.2, 
  1.47973}, {4.3, 1.4809}, {4.4, 1.48231}, {4.5, 1.48374}, {4.6, 
  1.48498}, {4.7, 1.48589}, {4.8, 1.4865}, {4.9, 1.4869}, {5., 
  1.48717}};

list2 = {{0.3, 1.70796}, {0.4, 1.69032}, {0.5, 1.66887}, {0.6, 1.65187}, {0.7,
   1.64455}, {0.8, 1.64575}, {0.9, 1.65089}, {1., 1.65581}};

list3 ={{4.1, 1.47892}, {4.2, 1.47973}, {4.3, 1.4809}, {4.4, 1.48231}, {4.5, 
  1.48374}, {4.6, 1.48498}, {4.7, 1.48589}, {4.8, 1.4865}, {4.9, 
  1.4869}, {5., 1.48717}};
```

and so on **until 10 lists** and all of them have different lengths with some having (x,y) sets as much as 30 (x1,y1),(x2,y2) ... (x30,y30) like that,

i want to list them list this in single excel sheet with two different options whichever you can guide,

**list 1 x,y values** (next list after two columns separation) -**list 2 x,y values**- (next list after two columns separation) -**list 3 x,y values****

**list 1 x,y values** (no separation)- **list 2 x,y values**- (no separation)- **list 3 x,y values**

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
array = Riffle[{list1, list2, list3}, {{{Null, Null}}}];
array = Flatten[Transpose /@ array, 1];
array = PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ array], Null] &  /@  array;
Export["data.xls", Transpose[array]]
```

`Riffle` puts the two empty columns between each of the lists.  `Flatten` produces a list of the spreadsheet columns.  `PadRight` makes each column the same length.  The final transpose gives us a list of spreadsheet rows, which can be exported.